# MySQL order by two fields, cluster fields

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been wondering how to order rows chronologically, but also keep rows with extra flag together.

Specifically, I have table with orders

Data:

```
| created     | customer | ...
| 2020-01-01  | xyz      | ...
| 2020-01-10  | abc      | ...
| 2020-01-12  | xyz      | ...
| 2020-01-15  | xyz      | ...
| 2020-01-19  | abc      | ...
| 2020-01-20  | abc      | ...
```

Desired result:

```
| created     | customer | ...
| 2020-01-01  | xyz      | ...
| 2020-01-12  | xyz      | ...
| 2020-01-15  | xyz      | ...
| 2020-01-10  | abc      | ...
| 2020-01-19  | abc      | ...
| 2020-01-20  | abc      | ...
```

So pretty much I need "ORDER BY customers, created", but "customers" need to be ordered by their oldest order.

I hope it makes sense. And thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join a query that returns the oldest order of each customer and sort the table first by that oldest date:

```
select o.*
from orders o 
inner join (
  select customer, min(created) created
  from orders
  group by customer
) c on c.customer = o.customer
order by c.created, o.customer, o.created
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jspxAhmBszxUpGYCqk8S58/0).
Results:

```
| created    | customer |
| ---------- | -------- |
| 2020-01-01 | xyz      |
| 2020-01-12 | xyz      |
| 2020-01-15 | xyz      |
| 2020-01-10 | abc      |
| 2020-01-19 | abc      |
| 2020-01-20 | abc      |
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from orders order by customer desc, created_date asc;
```

```
2020-01-01  xyz 
2020-01-12  xyz 
2020-01-15  xyz 
2020-01-10  abc 
2020-01-19  abc 
2020-01-20  abc
```

Comment: nah... it sorts by customer value, not by time of their order

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions in the `order by`.  So:

```
select t.*
from t
order by min(created) over (partition by customer),
         customer,
         created;
```

Note that `customer` is included after the minimum of the creation date.  This ensures that if two customers have the same creation date, their data is not all mixed together.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
select * from tablename
group by customer desc, created asc
```